# validation on html controls using jquery in asp.net c# on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

look like this article.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/validate-form-on-click-of-anchor-using-jquery/
but in this not mentioned how to stop button click until error completed.

so when we click on submit click and error occurred and submit click is fired on c# code i want to stop when error is displayed

Comment: you can use `onclientclick="return validateForm()"` to stop the server side call, Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Error Occurred, that means *Validation* failed. So, you should return `false`, so that it won't fire the *Button Click* Code Behind Event. Else return `true`, so that it goes to Code Behind *Click Event* after *Validation* is completed.

So, simply...

```
if(Validation failed)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, prevent default behavior and submit form with js after validation:

```
<form action="actionpage.asp" onsubmit="submitForm();" name="form">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form> 


function submitForm(){

    if(validationfails){

        return false;
    }
    else  {
        document.form.submit();
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop the default button behaviour (i.e. submitting the form) from firing straight away you need to return false at the end of your button click handler

e.g.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {

    // validate your form 
    $("#form1").validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            },
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                field: {
                    required: true,
                    digits:true
                }
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Obviously the validation rules you create will depend on your form